# Solving an ODE with square

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the IVP:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=\frac{x^2}{t^2}-2 \\ 
x(1)=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

This is what I got for now:

I solved the homogenous ODE to $x(t)=t$.

Then I variated the constant for which I got: $c'(t)=\frac{c^2-c-2}{t}$.

For this, I repeated the steps and got $c=\frac{1}{1-Kt}$ and variated the constant $K$ again.

But that's where I'm stuck and think I did something wrong because I can't solve it.

If someone could help me it'd be very nice.

Comment: you can't variate the constant since your ODE is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider this as a Riccati equation and employ the parametrization $x=-2\frac{u}{u'}$ so that
$$
\frac{4u^2}{t^2u'^2}-2 = x'=-2+2\frac{uu''}{u'^2}
\implies
t^2u''-4u=0,~~ u(1)=1,~u'(1)=-2.
$$
This now is an Euler-Cauchy equation with basis solutions $t^m$ where $m$ is the roots of the characteristic equation $m(m-1)-4=0$. Then
$$
x(t)=-2\frac{C_1t^{m_1}+C_2t^{m_2}}{m_1C_1t^{m_1-1}+m_2C_2t^{m_2-1}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, how did you find $y=-2\frac{u}{u'}$?

Comment: It's either that or $x(t)=-t^2\frac{u'}{u}$, then the resulting equation has more terms. You could in general try $x(t)=\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}$ and then declare a relations between $p$ and $q$ that simplifies the remaining equation. That works only for Riccati equations and, like here, what you will come up with are exactly these two variants.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I think I have one last question. I followed your hints and came to the conclusion that I can't specify what $C_1, C_2$ are. Is that the case for this IVP?

Comment: As you can cancel the one or the other coefficient in the fraction, there is really only one real parameter. Or you could arbitrarily decide that $u'(1)=-2$, so that then $u(1)=1$, and determine the coefficients from that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set $y(t)=tx(t).$ Then $$ty'(t)+y(t)=y(t)^2-1\iff \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)^2-y(t)-1}=\frac{1}{t}.$$